# ¿Cómo hago para que el contenido de una celda de mi tabla esté casi pegada al borde superior?

Tags: html, css

Tengo una tabla que indica el codigo de provincias Argentinas, y cuando hago el rowspan para cada una, me queda en el medio de la celda y queda fea a la vista.. Por lo que estoy jugando un poco con los estilos para ver cómo quedaría mejor...

Lo que quiero es que las dos celdas de la izquierda (Las que dicen "Región" y "Código") me queden casi pegadas al borde superior de la celda...Que casi lo toquen.

Intente haciendo `margin: 0;` `padding: 0;` pero no logré ningún resultado. Tambien con `cellspacing: 0;` y `cellpadding=0`.

Imaginemos que tengo esta tabla:

```css
table{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;">
            <table>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <td  rowspan="26"  style="text-align: left; font">Región</td>
                          <td  rowspan="26"  style="text-align: left">Código</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>00</td>
                          <td>Capital Federal</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>01</td>
                          <td>Buenos Aires</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>02</td>
                          <td>Catamarca</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>03</td>
                          <td>Córdoba</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                          <td>04</td>
                          <td>Corrientes</td>
                      </tr>
                      
                 </tbody>
                </table>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar vertical-align:top; acá hay un enlace con mayor información:
https://www.delftstack.com/es/howto/html/html-table-align-top/

Comment: Gracias!! funcionó perfecto.

Comment: Que bueno, un gusto poder ayudar.!